# SQL query for top 10 wins

Tags: mysql, sql

So i currently have a table set out like this

```
gameID | userID | WinLose 
1      | 1      | win
2      | 1      | win
3      | 1      | lose
4      | 2      | win
5      | 2      | lose
6      | 2      | win
```

It takes userID as a foreign key from a user table and records every game played, along with weather a user won or lost.

Can anyone tell me how I would write a query that would add up how many times each user won a game, and then list the 10 highest values?

I'm trying to display the top 10 users with the most wins.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: SO is a Q/A site, not a free coding service. Pls provide what you have tried and what issues you encountered with that attempt.

Comment: There are only 6 results

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: something like this, select count(gameID) wins, userID from yourWinLossTable where winlose="win" group by userID order by wins desc limit 10;

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `count` and `group by` clause to get a sum by user and then `order by` to sort results and get the top 10 with `limit`:

```
select userID
     , count(*) as total_wins 
from tbl 
where WinLose='win'
group by userID
order by total_wins desc
limit 10
```

or conditional `sum`:

```
select userID
     , sum(WinLose='win') as total_wins 
from tbl 
group by userID
order by total_wins desc
limit 10
```

Comment: `sum`? why not `count(*) ... where WinLose = 'win'`?